# Chrome on MacOS raises a "ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM" warning

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

I got the error `NET::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM` when accessing one website using Chrome browser on macOS. The url of the website is corporate / internal so I can't paste the url here (you won't have access anyhow).

Chrome version 75.0.3770.142.

macOS version is Mojave (10.14.4).

Chrome devtools Security tab show 2 errors:

1. Certificate - insecure (SHA-1) : The certificate chain for this site contains a certificate signed using SHA-1.
2. Certificate - missing : This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM).

[image: Devtool Security tab]

I can bypass the warning, but it come back after each page change/page refresh (so boring).

I know why the warning 1 is shown: the leaf certificate is signed with a certificate which signature algorithm is SHA-1 with RSA. Chrome detects this as weak. (I'm ok with this behavior)

I *guess* the warning 1 implies the warning 2: the leaf certificate can't be trusted.

The things I don't understand are:

1. why I don't have the problem using Firefox, on the same macOS computer
2. why I don't have the same problem using Chrome, same version, from another macOS computer
3. why I don't have the same problem using Chrome, same version, from a Windows computer

As a side note, Chrome on Windows computer show the same `Certificate - insecure (SHA-1)`, but the warning 2 `ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM` is not present.

This drives me crazy !

Does anyone have an idea on this ?

Does anyone knows how/when/why those warnings are raised ? (I may look into Chromium source code but I don't know if Chromium handles this mecanism)

I really don't understand why there are such different behavior on configurations that looks similars...

Thanks for your help,

Romain

Comment: Each browser is free to implement the level of security it wishes. Things change depending on their version also. Your question would have been better if you had shown the specific certificate triggering that. But since it is not related to programming you are unfortunately offtopic here.

Comment: I 100% agree with `Each browser is free`, but why it's OK with `Chrome 75.0.3770.142` on Windows, and KO on macOS then ? Even if it's the same version number, implementations (and thus whole browsers) are different ? If I'm off-topic, where else could I get some help ?

Comment: Browsers may use the cryptographic tools and libraries offered by the OS, hence they depend also on what the OS policies are. Again, you should start by showing the certificate and making 100% sure that you see the same one on each of your attempt from different browser/OS cases. Your question may be on topic for [su] or [webmasters.se] (if the question is about a website you control yourself) I guess, but read their respective help sections to find out the topics allowed or not.

Comment: " The url of the website is corporate" So did you reach out to your local sysadmins/network admins? They should surely be able to diagnose things like that for you and as you said it is internal and not reachable so it restricts the amount of troubleshooting outsiders can do. Also, due to corporate policies, your systems may have been configured in specific ways (injecting private CA, forcing all traffic through a proxy, etc.) that will change the results and can depend on many factors, including the OS.

Comment: You're right, I'll check if certificate are 100% identical (I've check main fields only, not all). Certs in this certs chain are company-specific, and not signed by a public CA (even the root one). So yes, we have private CA. But Root CA is imported in OS cert store, and marked as trusted. Also, there is a corporate proxy, but access to this URL does not pass trough it (only internet/external URL do reach the proxy). I may have specified this in my question. I can ask sysadmins too, but macOS computers are "out of their responsability", so... :( I'll ask website owner too. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is corporate, so the certificate is signed by your corporation. This is normal for many corporative sites/intranets.

1. Chrome assumes SHA1 is weak, but this is OK. It is the company certificate for the corporative intranet (i am assuming it is an intranet URL, or alike), so no problem it uses SHA1.
2. The site is missing a valid trusted certificate, means the current URL certificate could not be validated by any worldwide authority (this is normal, it was created by the intranet admin, internally, for internal use), and then the message is warning you that it is not trustable: **Not trustable here means** your computer does not know what to do, it tried check it to validate via internet if it could be trusted but it couldn't find any authority who replied, so the warning is for you to take some action (ignore, avoid the url, check the certificate, or trust it)

Solution:

On MacOS you have to add that certificate to the KeyChain, this way you are intentionally telling the operating system and any application who need to verify the certificate that it is trustable.

To do it:

- open the certificate by clicking "View Certificate" on Chrome (like it is on your image above)
- Once it is opened, click on its square drawing (difficult to explain this, I will put a picture below), and
- Drag the certificate to your desktop (or any folder, this is temporary)

[image: How to Drag the Certificate]

- Go to finder, double click the certificate you just saved, you will se a dialog box like the image below:

[image]

- Click Add (keychain must be login, like the above image)
- Keychain Utility should open automatically at this point, if it doesn't, open KeyChain Utility on your Mac. Locate the certificate inside the Login Keychain (example picture below)

[image]

- You'll see it was added, but yet not trusted. So we will tell the system we trust it, and by trusting it applications like Chrome and Safari will not display that warning anymore. Because they will check that the system trust that certificate for SSL connections.
- Double Click it on the Keychain, it will open, click the little triangle to expand "Trust" item.
- Select the item "Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)", and put the value "Always Trust"

[image]

- Close the certificate by clicking on the red X button on its window. It will ask for your password to save the new settings for the certificate.

[image]

- Put your password, click Update Settings

It will now show a blue icon, along with a message telling it is marked as trusted for your account.

[image]

This is it.

The Chrome messages will disappear because now that certificate is trusted.

**Note:** You may be thinking now... "I never did it on the other Mac" and you explained that you don't have that problem on Chrome on that other Mac. I suppose on the other Mac you have accessed that corporative URL using Safari at least once. When you access via Safari it will present you a similar warning like Chrome does, but if you ACCEPT it on Safari, it automatically does all this tutorial procedure for you transparently: it just ask if you want to proceed anyway, you click "proceed", Safari asks you for your password then it put the certificate on the keychain and mark it as trusted [**exactly like we did**] but transparently. And the next time you access the corporate URL you will not be asked because its certificate is already trusted on your keychain. Later if you then access it using Chrome it will not ask you, because it will see that the keychain already has that corporate certificate as trusted.

This is very probably why your other Mac does not have this situation.

PS: *I could have answered here just*: Access it using Safari, accept and proceed, and it will never ask again. But this would not be the correct answer. It would not explain the reason, and would be out of your presented *scenario*. So since you are using Chrome, I described this procedure considering the exact application and the exact situation that you have presented here, clarifying the reasons behind it.

Of course, now, since you know there is 2 ways to make this certificate installation procedure, you can opt for the one you like better.

_

---

Note: as mentioned by @patrick-mevzek

> "On MacOS you have to add that certificate to the KeyChain", and you
>   will need to to it again each time the certificate changes or is
>   renewed. And if signed by a private CA, and if you add the CA in the
>   trust store, you are then open to various MitM attacks, as this CA can
>   sign certificates for any name, which is/may typically be the standard
>   setup inside corporate PKIs, but you have to be aware of consequences.
>   "

---

I agree with @patrick-mevzek, he is right and he made an important observation on this topic.

I'm extending the point he mentioned (specifically for MacOS) by showing how you can check if the corporate certificate you are about to add to your keychain is a CA Certificate or just a common innofensive end-to-end SSL certificate.

Open that certificate again, scroll down the information of it, until you find the item **"usage"** as shown on the picture below.

On the image below, there are 2 kind of certificates:

1. on the left, there is a CA Certificate: it **can be used** as MitM decryptor if your company wanted. It would only require a proxy between you and the internet, where your browser traffic would passes through. And if you have this kind of certificate trusted on your keychain, you have to be aware that the company proxy can (if a malicious admin wanted) decrypt your encrypted HTTPS traffic and log every confidential information on your connection to anywhere.
2. on the right, there is a simple and common SSL Certificate used by all of websites and internet domains, its purpose is just end-to-end encryption between you and the visited domain, to encrypt your traffic. It cannot be used as a MitM decryptor of your connection traffic data. This kind is totally safe to be trusted on your keychain.

[image]

Let's consider that you have the dangerous case, which the certificate is a CA Certificate and you added and trusted it.

**Is there a way for you to know if your traffic is being decrypted by your company and your information being exposed?**

Yes, there is.

On any browser, when you are accessing any important site, choose a bank for example, for this example I am choosing "hsbc.com.br", and I will show both situations:

- The normal end-to-end encryption as it always must be
- The MitM situation decrypting the banking sensitive private data.

While accessing any important https site, even if you see the Green icon on chrome or safari telling the connection is encrypted, check the certificate of it if you want to be sure that nobody is in the middle.

_

**Here is the normal & SECURE situation:** 
HSBC Certificate is issued by DigiCert Inc and also is of type EV, which offer stronger guarantee of identity.

[image]

---

Now lets put a proxy in the middle, and do the MitM atack.

Here is the same HSBC bank I just acessed minutes ago, but I inserted a MitM proxy technic on my network, and **I trusted that kind of certificate** [CA Certificate] on my MacOS keychain.

Let's see what Chrome tells about the banking website:

[image]

It is telling me that it is secure, and also says that my information will be private!

But Chrome is WRONG!! (And it doesn't know it is wrong, because it is beyond it)

Lets open the certificate again: (I just activated the proxy and reloaded the page)
[image]

---

It is easy to notice the difference, the fake HSBC certificate was issued by my own personal certificate authority inside my network. This was done automatically by my proxy, which is capable of reading all the information I insert on the HSBC bank website, in pure TXT format, in both ways. Then it encrypts the data again and send to my Browser, and vice versa, do the same re-encryption while talking to HSBC servers.

The browser "think" that everything is OK, because the connection is encrypted, the site name on the certificate MATCHES the URL address I am accessing, the certificate is valid, and the CA Authority it is trusted on my keychain!

Everything technically is fine, except that is not.

This is the real danger, exposed, as mentioned by @patrick-mevzek that you have to be aware.

Comment: "On MacOS you have to add that certificate to the KeyChain", and you will need to to it again each time the certificate changes or is renewed. And if signed by a private CA, and if you add the CA in the trust store, you are then open to various MitM attacks, as this CA can sign certificates for any name, which is/may typically be the standard setup inside corporate PKIs, but you have to be aware of consequences.

Comment: thanks for your very detailed answer. I never stared Safari on this computer so this is out of topic (but thanks for this information). Also, unfortunately, root CA is *already* in the mac keystore, and is trusted (I've done your procedure before posting this question here). And the Chrome warning is still displayed... That's exactly why this problem drives me crazy, and I ask for help :(

Comment: Well, that is weird. I just tested here a similar situation using a web address on internet that still has SHA1 certificate, on Chrome for Mac, and it complained about the security of the certificate, then I inserting the site certificate on my keychain, chrome stoped complaining about the site and accessed it transparently, with a SHA1 cert. If you have time to try it, this is the address, specifically for testing HTTPS with SHA1: https://sha1-2016.badssl.com . The only difference from my setup and yours is our Chrome version, mine is: Version 76.0.3809.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)